# How to limit a type to the class of a interface and not the instance of that interface?

Tags: type-inference, crystal-lang

Given the following *Interface* in a module:

```
module Action
  abstract def perform
end
```

I would like to use it to instantiate different classes that implement it:

```
class Run
  include Action

  def perform
    puts "run!"
  end
end

class Jump
  include Action

  def perform
    puts "jump!"
  end
end
```

I know is possible to define an array like `[] of Action` and be able to store instances of `Action`, but I'm interested on the classes instead of the instances.

I would like to know how to define the type restriction so I can store a reference to the **class** that implements the interface and not an specific instance.

My objective is be able to instantiate a fresh instance of certain class and be able to invoke the `perform` method in it.

At this time it is possible to write the following code:

```
actions = [Run, Jump]
actions.each do |klass|
  instance = klass.new.as(Action)
  instance.perform
end
```

And things will work, however it will not be possible to store that list of classes into a instance variable since the type restrictions are a bit more strict.

What would be the type restriction syntax for that case?

Comment: What's the reason to instantiate a fresh instance each time, instead of using the same one?

Comment: @asterite a dev might be altering instance variables in the perform. Having this called across multiple fibers/threads might lead into issues. AFAIK a fresh instance is the best scenario.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first idea that comes to mind is using `[] of Action.class`, but that doesn't work. Maybe that should work, but it will need a change/enhancement in the compiler.

In the meantime you can do this:

```
module Action
  abstract def perform
end

class Run
  include Action

  def perform
    puts "run!"
  end
end

class Jump
  include Action

  def perform
    puts "jump!"
  end
end

module ActionFactory
  abstract def new : Action
end

struct GenericActionFactory(T)
  include ActionFactory

  def new
    T.new
  end
end

ary = [] of ActionFactory
ary << GenericActionFactory(Run).new
ary << GenericActionFactory(Jump).new

action = ary[0].new
p action

action = ary[1].new
p action
```

Comment: Wouldn't in that case the compiler infere `T` as `Jump | Run`? Wouldn't that be a bit heavy when actions can be in the order of 100+?

Comment: The compiler internally represents all module implementations as a union, so it would be the same. At least for now I don't think it will make a difference. In the long the run we might improve this.

Answer (score 1):

An alternative approach to the Factory suggestion made by @asterite is the usage of a module and `extend` it on the class but also use it to define the type of the instance variables:

```
module Action
  module Interface
  end

  macro included
    extend Interface
  end

  abstract def perform
end

class Run
  include Action

  def perform
    puts "run!"
  end
end

class Jump
  include Action

  def perform
    puts "jump!"
  end
end

list = [] of Action::Interface
list << Run
list << Jump

list.each do |klass|
  instance = klass.new
  instance.perform
end
```

This allowed me to also use `Action.class` as type requirement so only classes that implement `Action` can be used and using `Action::Interface` removed the need to perform any casting on the element obtained from the array:

```
class Worker
  @actions = [] of Action::Interface

  def add(action : Action.class)
    @actions << action
  end

  def perform
    @actions.each do |klass|
      instance = klass.new
      instance.perform
    end
  end
end

a = Worker.new
a.add Run
a.add Jump
a.add Jump
a.perform
```